# Polyjuice Potion and Injuries Timeline

Tags: harry-potter, polyjuice-potion

A question similar to [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52300/how-do-injuries-work-with-polyjuice-potion), but a little different. We know as mentioned in the tagged question that Polyjuice potion will account for injuries, such as Mad-Eye's in Goblet of Fire. How tight is the timeline though?

Say Person A were to steal a hair from person B to use in Polyjuice potion, and then Person B were to receive some large and noticeable injury, would Person A assume that injury with the potion, or would they need to grab a new hair?

Comment: First guess was new hair, but can't even say why exactly. But then again, maybe not  ... Magic!

Comment: So save some of your hair from when you were young, then polyjuice yourself back to your own youth for a vacation from your doddering senility later in life

Comment: Well can you polyjuice into a dead dude?

Comment: the other question asks your specific question in its body. ""That is, if you take a Polyjuice, and while you're still under its effects, the person being transformed into gets injured (or even dies), will that injury be transferred onto you?" "-- with an answer of probably not.

Comment: @Himarm If I'm understanding this question correctly, it's asking about what happens if person B is injured after person A gets the hair but **before person A takes the potion**. Whereas the old one is asking about what happens if person B is injured **while person A is under the effect of the potion**. Not a duplicate.

Comment: @Randal'Thor second answer also covers this

Comment: @Himarm You mean the poorly written and unsourced answer way down at the bottom of the page? It's *possible* that addresses this question, but even if it does, I don't think that's enough to warrant a dupehammer.

Comment: @Randal'Thor posted an answer to the otherone since i didnt like either answer anyway

Comment: as an update, check my answer on the duped question, i think you'll find it answers your question