# Why did Crouch Jr. transform into a healthy version of Moody?

Tags: harry-potter, polyjuice-potion, barty-crouch-jr

How could Barty Crouch Jr. assume Mad-Eye Moody's healthy figure, if he was taking Polyjuice Potion taken from a feeble and weak Moody? Isn't the Polyjuice Potion supposed to make you look like the person you want to turn yourself into in the exact way this person looks at the moment when the potion is taken? I would think that Barty Crouch Jr. would be looking weaker and weaker along with the decay of the real Moody locked in the trunk.

Comment: I'm assuming Crouch was smart enough to properly feed Moody, in order to maintain his appearance. Crouch was a [pretty bright wizard](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95875/how-could-barty-crouch-jr-perform-such-powerful-magic).

Comment: But doesn't it say when they find him that he's gotten weak and feeble? OTOH, maybe Crouch foresaw this and took a TON of hair right at the start.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/52300/51379

Comment: But the answers on that topic do not get to the question that Crouch had been taking chunks of hair after Moody's imprisonment, which supposedly would make him look like Moody at the moment when the hair was taken, not before or after. @Adamant

Comment: @Paula this answer does: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/141577/14710