Why didn't Barty Crouch Jr. look like Alastor Moody at the end of the year?
In Goblet of Fire, Alastor Moody was trapped in a magical trunk and had become slim and had bald patches on his head by the time that Barty Crouch Jr. took Harry to his office after Voldemort's return. However, Barty Crouch Jr. looked like Alastor Moody from the beginning of the year, when he was freshly captured by Barty Crouch Jr. and Peter Pettigrew. Did he use Human Transfiguration to alter the discrepancies/differences from the pre-start of the year appearance Alastor Moody.

This question is similar to: How do injuries work with Polyjuice Potion?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Main dupe is this one really: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/149241/why-did-crouch-jr-transform-into-a-healthy-version-of-moody but the dupe target does address the Moody appearance discrepancy directly
